# How to transfer data from a socket.io Service to an Activity

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, android-service

Currently, I have a `Service` that is supposed to keep a [socket.io](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) connection open for multiple different `Activity`s to use.  One of the biggest functions of the application is to update an album-art gallery whenever a song is added to a playlist.  The Node.js server broadcasts if a song is added, and my goal is for the `SocketService` to update the UI when `.on("song added"...` is triggered.  However, currently, I cannot figure out how to transfer the incoming data to the UI from the `SocketService`.  How would I go about doing this?

For reference:

The `"song add"` command from the server emits a `JSONObject`.

```
public class SocketService extends IntentService {
Socket socket;
String roomID;
String userID;
ArrayList<JSONObject> queuedSongs;
ArrayList<JSONObject> suggestionSongs;
int users;

public SocketService() {
    super("SocketService");
}



@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    userID = intent.getExtras().getString("userid", "0");
    Log.i("SocketService", "userID=" + userID);
    roomID = intent.getExtras().getString("code");
    Log.i("SocketService", "roomID=" + roomID);
    super.onCreate();
    try {
        socket = IO.socket("server address");
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.i("Internet-Task", "Connected to "server address"");
            }

        }).on("song add", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                try {
                    suggestionSongs.add(new JSONObject(args[0].toString()));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        //**//

        socket.io().on(Manager.EVENT_TRANSPORT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Transport transport = (Transport) args[0];

                transport.on(Transport.EVENT_REQUEST_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) args[0];
                        // modify request headers
                        headers.put("userid", Arrays.asList(userID));
                        headers.put("roomid", Arrays.asList(roomID));
                    }
                });
        socket.connect();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getCanonicalName(), e.toString());
    }
```

Additionally, here is the call to the service made in the `Activity` `onCreate()`.  No new thread is made prior.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SocketService.class);
    Bundle serviceBundle = new Bundle();
    serviceBundle.putString("code", roomID);;
    serviceBundle.putString("userid", userID);
    serviceIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
    startService(serviceIntent);
```

Again, my question is:  How do I transfer data from my `SocketService` to the UI of my `Activity`?

Comment: Perhaps callbacks? Commonly used in the Observer pattern (which is what you're essentially doing by listening to data changes). Otherwise, you're welcome to lookup the EventBus library

Comment: let your `Activity` bind to your `Service` using "bound local service" pattern and you will be able to pass the data directly from your `Service` to your `Activity`